# Type '{ domain: any; domainDispatch: React.Dispatch<any>; }' is not assignable to type 'string'

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-hooks

I have a a small file that looks like the following:

```
import React, { createContext, useContext, useReducer } from 'react'

const initState = ''
const DomainContext = createContext(initState)

export const CHANGE = 'CHANGE'
export const CLEAR = 'CLEAR'

const domainReducer = (state, action) => {
  switch (action.type) {
    case CHANGE:
      return action.value
    case CLEAR:
      return ''
    default:
      return state
  }
}
interface IDomainProviderProps {
  children: any
}

export const DomainProvider = ({ children }: IDomainProviderProps) => {
  const [domain, domainDispatch] = useReducer(domainReducer, initState)
  const domainData = { domain, domainDispatch }

  return <DomainContext.Provider value={domainData}>{children}</DomainContext.Provider>
}

export const useDomainContext = () => useContext(DomainContext)
```

I cannot figure out why I am getting the following type error on the following line:

The Error:

```
Type '{ domain: any; domainDispatch: React.Dispatch<any>; }' is not assignable to type 'string'.ts(2322)
```

The line:

```
  return <DomainContext.Provider value={domainData}>{children}</DomainContext.Provider>
```

Any ideas how to correctly type this to fix the error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The context value is an object with the shape: `{ domain, domainDispatch }`. So you need to give a correct shape type as the generic parameter for `createContext`. For more usage of React and Typescript, see [React TypeScript Cheatsheet#Context](https://react-typescript-cheatsheet.netlify.app/docs/basic/getting-started/context/)

```
import React, { createContext, useContext, useReducer } from 'react';

interface DomainContextInterface {
  domain: string;
  domainDispatch: React.Dispatch<any>;
}
const DomainContext = createContext<DomainContextInterface | null>(null);

export const CHANGE = 'CHANGE';
export const CLEAR = 'CLEAR';

const domainReducer = (state = '', action) => {
  switch (action.type) {
    case CHANGE:
      return action.value;
    case CLEAR:
      return '';
    default:
      return state;
  }
};
interface IDomainProviderProps {
  children: any;
}

export const DomainProvider = ({ children }: IDomainProviderProps) => {
  const [domain, domainDispatch] = useReducer(domainReducer, '');
  const domainData = { domain, domainDispatch };

  return <DomainContext.Provider value={domainData}>{children}</DomainContext.Provider>;
};

export const useDomainContext = () => useContext(DomainContext);
```

package version:

```json
"react": "^16.14.0",
"typescript": "^4.4.2"
```

Comment: Great, this solved it. Cheatsheet is a great resource.